# Error on generating purchasing contract in Word using SQL on Access: "Syntax error in FROM clause."

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, ms-access-2010

I have a template which I want to use to generate purchasing contracts in Microsoft Word. It uses contract clauses from a database dependant on the type of goods purchased. In a simplified form it is:

```
<invantive:foreach block="contract">
<invantive:value-of expression="$F{contractname}" />
<invantive:value-of expression="$F{counterparty}" />

Here the clauses of the purchasing agreement:
<invantive:foreach query="select * from   contract_items join headers on headers.headerid = contract_items.headerid where contractcat=coalesce($F{contractcat}, contractcat)">
<invantive:value-of expression="$F{itemname}" />
<invantive:value-of expression="$F{itemtext}" />
</invantive:foreach>
</invantive:foreach>
```

When I publish the template, I get an error on the SQL generated:

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

The query in the error window is:

```
select * from   contract_items join headers on headers.headerid = contract_items.headerid where contractcat=coalesce(@f0, contractcat)
```

When I used an identical data model in SQL Server, it works fine, but I want to run Composition with Access and don’t have access to the SQL Server environment at this moment.
How can I get this working on MS Access? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, does Access support, for example, COALESCE?

Comment: Try replacing COALESCE() with NZ()

Comment: Did you copy/paste from SSMS?  There might be some hidden characters that Access doesn't like.

Comment: "I've search on google; Access doesn't seem to support the coalesce part of the ANSI SQL syntax, but after correcting it I am still getting the same error. Maybe this fixed another error but I can't get it working. Can you help me with a tip?"

Comment: SSMS is I guess sql server management studio? No, the query is in a Microsoft Word template written with Invantive Composition

Comment: Do you want data to flow from Excel as a database to Word generating instruction documents? Or the other way around? What is your question?